# Textbox in ag-grid pagination

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We have a feature where we have to add a textbox in pagination and when user enters a page number,it should take the user to that specified page. Is it possible to use text box in ag grid pagination ? Say, for eg: Go to page no:10 something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably add that by poking nodes into the DOM, but I wouldn't recommend it.
You can, however, supply your own status bar component, containing a custom pagination control.

See the official docs at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-status-bar-component/